# How to get Peer IP Address in Nitrogen

Tags: erlang, nitrogen

Is is there a built in function in nitrogen framework to get Peer IP address? 
If not, is there a way to get the IP address of peer which is making to request to Nitrogen App

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the remote peer's address using [`wf_platform:get_peername/0`](http://github.com/rklophaus/nitrogen/blob/master/src/lib/wf_platform.erl#L112).

```
@spec wf_platform:get_peername() -> {ok, {Address, Port}} | {error, posix()}
    Address = {N1,N2,N3,N4} | {K1,K2,K3,K4,K5,K6,K7,K8}
    Port = int()
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Nitrogen2, the function to do this is `wf:peer_ip/0`. It doesn't seem to appear in any docs at the moment, but it does almost the same thing `wf_platform:get_peername()` used to.

```
wf:peer_ip/0 -> {A, B, C, D} | {A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H} 
%% example output: {127, 0, 0, 1}
```